# How to have a global exception handling in dll in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exception

Dll has no entry point in C#, so i need to put the code for global exception handling in one place as these dlls are referenced in exe and all have there try catch but there are some errors due to which it is crashing and to identify we are trying to create a crash dump. Can anyone suggest is it the feasible solution to do that or anything else has to be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, put the exception handling code in the executable where the code is actually being executed.

Comment: We have tried it, with Application.ThreadException also in Main of exe in program.cs, it is not touching that, we get a default dotnet window for the errors in dll and asks us to continue by ignoring the error.

Comment: Make sure to read and follow [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) for `Application.ThreadException`. Remember that running the app with the debugger attached changes some things about the default exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

As Cody said you should enclose every call to that dll in a try catch block to handle the exception. Your statement is a bit confusing I am assuming you are already using try catch block. If that's the case you can handle global exceptions as well to make sure it's not the exe itself throwing exception.

For example in Win Form application you can handle  [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) to catch global exceptions. You can also try with handling [AppDomain.Unhandled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event

Comment: I have tried that, but there are some exceptions which are not caught by try catch and making the application to crash. If it is caught we are handling it, if not caught is a problem.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting exceptions in unmanaged code.  This would cause the exception to crash the system.