# Any way to handle Unhandled exceptions at DLL level (Winforms plugin DLL)

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have a global exception handling in dll in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815074/how-to-have-a-global-exception-handling-in-dll-in-c)

I have known it at AppDomain level, but since I am a DLL plugin into the framework, so I want to be able to handle unhandled exceptions all at one place in my DLL.

By the way, if there is no such mechanism, then is the solution this:

**Put try-catch in code of every event handler (where exception is likely)**

I am currently handling in every event handler code and sometimes when it gets missed and the unhandled exception throws, then it disfigures the UI controls, and it becomes difficult to recover back other than restart the App.

Comment: This can't come to a good end.  Fix the bug, don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @Hans  do you mean fix the bug and not rely on try catch ?  but if bugs not found at test time exist then to user we have to give elegant recovery/breakdown.. cant rip his UI with unhandled. infact in the catch I log those and next time fix it. cant ever be sure 100% bug free :-)

Comment: AppDomain.UnhandledException tells you everything you need to know after you shipped your code and it is bombing on the user's machine.  Make sure it gets from that machine to yours.

Comment: but AppDomain.UnhandledException is not in my control. the framework subscribes to it (i only control my plugin DLL) and handles these exceptions. I dont get to see/do anything with those. And my UI control bombs on unhandled exception.